# How to scroll the outside scrollView not inside scrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a scrollView and inside it some scrollViews , and everyone have a webview to show html file, using this method I will zooming every html file , but Now I found that when I scroll the html file it didn't work. I think I scroll the scrollview inside and it autosize the html file , but How to let the scrollview inside not to call the scroll function and when I scroll the html it can call the scroll function outside, and I have disable the scroll property of inside scrollview, but it didn't work, and How to do with it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

UIScrollView in UIScrollView is a common use. See apple stocks app...

I am trying to send ScrollView Gesture events like pan and zoom from outside the scrollview itself. It doesn't look like apple lets you send to the UIScrollViews handlePan: and handleZoom: methods

Answer (score 0):

A quote from UIScrollView Class reference :-

> Important: You should not embed
>   UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so,
>   unexpected behavior can result because
>   touch events for the two objects can
>   be mixed up and wrongly handled

I would add : "You should not embed UIScrollView objects in UIScrollView "

Comment: ok, at first I load some webviews into scrollview and I want to zoom these webviews but I don't get it. So I think maybe add some scrollviews around webview, but it didn't work, so have another way to zoom webview in scrollview, Thank you !